# How can I solve this PCB problem in Altium?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, altium

I tried to change width size and also design rules wizard, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

[image: screenshot]

The problem is small circles. They shouldn't be on the components and I tried to fix with design rules.

Comment: Which problem are you referring to?

Comment: I couldnt add the picture so there are cross(ı mean 'x') inside the circles on the components in pcbdoc file

Comment: please upload the picture to imgur.com and add a link to it to your question.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/kqvn6pp here is the link thanks for help:)

Comment: That picture is far too small to be useful. And it still doesn't explain what the *problem* is.

Comment: https://imgur.com/LgUjShj is that clear now? The problem is small circles. İt shouldnt be on the components and ı tried to fix with design rules but ım new in altium so ı couldnt fix the problem

Comment: The small green circles are error markers. It means that at least one of your design rules are violated. You can reset the error markers by using `Tools>Reset Error Markers`. You should consider reviewing your errors, fix them, or modify your design rules accordingly.

Comment: When you right click the component and show violations, what does it say?

Comment: It worked with resetting error makers thank you so much. But is the problem solved now? I mean ı cant see the green circles but in the background there is no problem about components right?

Answer (score 1):

Altium has a feature called "Rooms" that allows you to define zones on your board when you want certain components to be (or not). If you don't know it is active, then you'll get the error message shown in your screenshot:

[image]

Solution if you don't want to use that feature:

Project properties > Class generation > uncheck "create room".

Go to rules, search Room, delete rule for Room definition.

Also delete the Room.

Comment: I also tried your solution I unchecked "create room" but ı didnt see any room tool to delete thank you so much.